# Pause/resume a thread instead of start/stoping in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have created a unity project. In the Start() method I have created a `thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(zip));` a new thread of my method zip. In stop_rec() method I am starting the thread.

```
void stop_recording(){
    .... 
    thread.Start ();

}
```

This method it is called 3-4 times. Therefore the thread it is starting and stoping three-four times. Is there a way to pause/resume the thread instead of start stop it?

Comment: Read this msdn article about pausing and resuming `Threads` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tttdef8x(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Thread.Sleep(Your_Pause_Duration);`

Comment: You could call a Method which Pauses the thread you would like to pause